# How to hide the tabs for a web application user based on his role

Tags: jquery, spring, tomcat

I am creating a web application using spring and on tomcat server. Once the user logs into this application, he will be accessing 3 pages which will be shown as tabs. But when an admin logs in, he will be shown one more extra page(an extra tab in UI) for performing admin functions. I know this can be achieved by setting up roles and using jdbc realm configuration in tomcat. But, I don't want to show(or) give the right to the fourth page for any normal user. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented spring security in your application then you should use spring security JSP tags to show and hide components.

Add following taglib on your JSP page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

Following code shows that, enclosed code will execute only if user role is admin.

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
    //admin tab you want to show goes here
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question but think about using spring security. 
You can follow up the tutorial on http://krams915.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_5023.html

For user based tabs, u can use spring security jsp tags to hide specific tabviews against user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using Spring Security or not, you can always do this:

```
<jstl:if test="request.isUserInRole('somerole')">
  <!-- put your code for tab #4 in here -->
</jstl:if>
```